# Desktop app/widget development using web technology stack

Tags: google-chrome

I want to develop a desktop application/widget, and would love to use a web technology stack. so I can...

1. Reuse existing skills
2. Run on multiple platforms (OsX, Windows)
3. Update application code without having the user upgrade (part/all of the code gets downloaded from the web)

Running in a browser is probably the best option, but one thing that is getting in the way is the browser's chrome (frame, tabs menus etc.) and background, as I want to create a transparent application (e.g. a semi-transparent, round clock that would display on top of other apps).

I'm thinking that a custom version of a browser (chrome or firefox) is probably the answer. All I would need to do is have a shortcut like:

```
...\chrome.exe -transparent -no_chrome ...\mywidget.html
```

Seems to me like a fairly obvious need, so before I consider forking chromium, I'm thinking there must be something like this already.

I know there's http://awesomium.com/ ($2,900 license cost), but it is an overkill as I don't need to embed a browser into a desktop app, API and all, and the cost is prohibitively high for a low-cost, limited distribution app.

There is also http://mozillalabs.com/chromeless/ but it doesn't seem actively maintained.

In addition, for both options, the installation overhead is huge (installing a full-fledged browser for the sake of running a widget).

Any suggestions? (please not Adobe Air - I want to use a standard web tech stack)

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Pretty much all OSs offer "widgets" in some form or another, which are usually done using HTML+CSS+JS.

Comment: Sure, but these are idiosyncratic to the specific OS you'd be running this on, no? (except for google gadgets which are defunct)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this discussion for several options

http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2829126

-FT